# enter qty and update total order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just making a very very simple order form.

Want a input box ( only accept numbers )

User enters a quantity , lets say 50

We have a multiplier value which is lets say 10

Want a disabled form field, showing the result of 50 x 10

So form field would show 500

so now we have variable **orderTotal** we can pass to our code like:

```
$txtAmount = "orderTotal";
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: what do you mean? passing php value to javascript?

Comment: i think you want a simple shopping cart a lot of tutorials in web like http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/building-a-simple-php-shopping-cart

Comment: No not php, in fact its client side so hence js. Just need a input field a user can enter number in, and a total field that multiplies that number by a preset value.

Comment: @422, sent you a mail through you website, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code must be somewhat similar. but not tested. if you find error then please let me know

EDIT:: the tested code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function (){


    $("#value").blur(
        function(){         
            var value  = $(this).val();
            if(isInt(value)){
                $("#total").val($(this).val()*$("#quantity").val());                
            }
            else{
                alert('pelase enter int');
            }       

        }
    );
    $('#quantity').change(
        function()
        {
            var value =$("#value").val(); 
            if(isInt(value))
            {
                if($("#quantity").val() > 0){
                    $("#total").val($(this).val()*$("#value").val());
                }                       
            }
            else{
                alert('pelase enter int');
            }
        }
    )

    });

  function isInt(x) {
   var y=parseInt(x);
   if (isNaN(y)) return false;
   return x==y && x.toString()==y.toString();
  }
</script>

<form>
    <input id="value" name="value" />
    <select id="quantity">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>50</option>
    </select>       
</form>
<input id="total" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

update:: this should work but not sure .. if not working then let me know

Comment: yeah thanks but thats not it. I dont want user to have to click anything, and they have no choice as to the mutiplier. That is set for example. They choose how many widgets they want, we have preset price to say 10. So they choose 50 and a disabled field, automatically displays 500

Comment: @422 in that case please have a look at update. but code is not tested

Comment: Hmm @explorex, isnt doing anything for me. Thanks for your persistence though.

Comment: It does work. The drop down isnt a pre selectable item. Its fixed at say 10 and doesnt need to be dispalyed to the user.
The update does not work if the element is an input field like: <input id="total"> any suggestions

Comment: @422 well replace 'html(total)' by 'val(total)' however i will edit the code again

Comment: 90% of the way there thanks, voted for it. Just need to set the value ( rather than options ) and also update the input field, without having to click anywhere ( so its automated ) and it would be perfect. Thanks @ explorex

Comment: @422 if you got any problems then, please comment,  ... :)

Answer (score 1):

@explorex has you most of the way there, but one thing I'd be cautious about is floating point math in Javascript is not precise.  If you're dealing with money... you want to make sure you're precise.

Here's a SO question with answers about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/javascript-bigdecimal-library

Comment: thanks Sean ( we are dealing in whole numbers only ) So all multiples of 10 or 11